# Swift/Xcode - Get value of random functions with breakpoint; at creation point / before usage?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a couple of functions in my game that in this example spawns enemies (monsters), at the very top of the function i have created a set of variables, etc:

```
let MonsterRandomType = arc4random_uniform(3)
let MonsterRandomRotation = arc4random_uniform(3)
```

And a dussin other variables that determine various properties of the enemies, the game started out as an endless runner and basically everything was made up of randomizations.

Now i decided to create levels/maps that is repeatable or have hardcoded values instead of randomness. I figured i reuse my existing functions for creating random game levels, run the game and save the random values created and use them in my hardcoded levels, i did this by setting break points on my var's and let's, iterating through them and saving as json into a file from the log, it did not work since, for whatever reason, when using random functions like arc4random_uniform the debugger and breakpoint doesn't actually set/get the value before the variable is being used further down into my code where the variables are used in if or switch statements.

If i set a breakpoint at:

```
let MonsterRandomType = arc4random_uniform(3)
```

And then test it by hitting the "Print Description" button to get more info about the variable in the output window in Xcode i will get this "error":

```
Printing description of MonsterRandomType:
(UInt32) MonsterRandomType = <variable not available>
```

Now i obviously know that i can achieve what i want (getting the value of every variable that is using a random_function) by setting the breakpoint where these variables are being used further down into the code but its very inefficient to go through many, many lines of code and many, many functions when all the variables is at the top of every function/file.

If i do the following:

```
print(arc4random_uniform(3))
```

The output window will show the value created by the random function as soon as it is created, but why cant the debugger and breakpoint show the value when it is created? Seems it can only show the value when the variable is first used further down into the code.

If i did:

```
let MonsterRandomType = 1
```

The debugger would identify the value, in the debugger it would say: "MonsterRandomType = (Int) 1". So the debugger obviously can get values as soon as the variable is created and the variable is attributed the value instantly, unless that value is created by a random_function like arc4random_uniform which is very annoying. Is it possible to fix this behaviour?

[Image of breakpoint example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzlpS.png)

Comment: When you stop at a line due to a breakpoint, that line has not been executed yet which is why you can't print the value. Think of a breakpoint as stopping at the line of code it is going to run next.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however as my provided pictures show, i am currently at the breakpoint on line 56, but i still can't "inspect" or get the values of the variable at line 53. So the variable at line 53 should have gotten a value by the time i stopped at line 56, shouldn't it? It works for hardcoded values at line 53 when stopping at line 56, but not with random functions like ar4random_uniform()